# How to partially initialize a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance

I have `LinkClass` which has 12 methods and 10 imports.

This class has main public method `open`. I want to improve page speed by these steps:

1. Develop the basic implementation of `LinkClass`, where there will be no heavy 10 imports and 11 methods
2. Create the open method without implementation, which will queue all calls
3. Load the basic implementation of the class
4. After the site is loaded, initialize the full implementation of the `LinkClass` and handle all the passed links which was pushed to queue

**Current implementation of `LinkClass`**

```
import env from './env'
import loader from './loader'
// ...(etc)

class LinkClass {
  public open(url: string) {}
  canOpen(url: string) {}
  // ...other methods
}
```

**Basic implementation**

```
class LinkClass {
      private queue: string = []
      public open(url) {
        this.queue.push(url)
      }
      // need call when site is loaded
      public load() {}
}
```

Could you help me, how can I load the entire implementation of the class after loading the site?

Comment: How do you know this is the bottleneck?

Comment: Just make methods that are heavy use a dynamic import, it does mean these methods will need to be `async`, but with modern JS this is not really a big deal these days.  eg.  You could have something like -> `async heavy() { const {heavy} = import('./heavy'); return heavy(); }`